# How to download windows 10 ISO from a windows machine

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

On my mac if I go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO I get:

[image]

On windows I get:

[image]

Is there any way to download the ISO without being required of downloading the update first?
The reason is that my windows experience never really get's better after windows updates, and I kind of don't care about them anymore. They fail half the time and apart from security, they add nothing of value as far as I can tell.